# installing packages in Anaconda stopped

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, python-docx

i have been using Anaconda for installing python packages and so far it worked just fine.

Since today it doesn't ... I am able to select the package i want, in my case "python-docx", run apply, and anaconda finds the package. I am also able to start the installtion and it does something (at least the processing bar keeps running), but after a view minutes it stopps. But nothing has happened. The package is still marked as not installed and wound't work in the code.

I tried it with different packages, but it is always the same.
I also tried to install the package using the conda comment in the cmd-box but here i end up with the error "conda comment hast not been found".

Does anyone know what i can do ?

Comment: if you're using windows you can open Anaconda prompt and install packages as `conda install <package-name>`

Comment: What OS and OS version do you work on? What anaconda version do you use? What do the logs say? "run apply" is sth I cannot do in my command-line anaconda. Thus you also use some kind of front-end to access it, maybe Anaconda Navigator? Please quote any error message you receive verbatim (use copy&paste). The one you quote has at least a typo, I recon, but I cannot tell for sure.

Comment: I work on Windows 10 and am using Anaconda Navigator.